# Installing Carrot2 on Windows7, 8 or 10

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, carrot2

I am trying to install carrot2-workbench-win32.win32.x86_64-3.15.1 on a 32-bit Windows 7. I get an error "the version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows you're running".

[Error pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmSfW.png)

I have JDK8 installed and running all right.

Any suggestions? Do I need to recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We stopped publishing 32-bit builds some time ago, here's the latest 32-bit build:

http://download.carrot2.org/stable/3.13.0/carrot2-workbench-win32.win32.x86-3.13.0.zip

To get the 32-bit binaries of the latest version, you'd indeed need to compile from sources.

Comment: Ok. Cool. Got it. I'll use the 32-bits to test. So the latest releases are 64-bits?

Comment: Yes, the latest versions are 64-bit only.